# Calculating the distance between 2 positions in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe [df] such as this one:

```
id  pos1                 pos2
1   -103.3671_43.0835    -103.3660_43.0812  
2   -103.3634_43.0855    -103.3656_43.0872  
3   -103.3684_43.0884    -103.3695_43.0890  
4   -103.3613_43.0835    -103.3600_43.0825
```

I would like to know whether there is a way of calculating the distance between pos1 and pos2 in meters?

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, first split the columns, so that you have lon/lat columns for each position. Then use `raster::pointDistance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
p1 <- as.data.frame(`class<-`(do.call(rbind,strsplit(df$pos1,"_")),"numeric"))
p2 <- as.data.frame(`class<-`(do.call(rbind,strsplit(df$pos2,"_")),"numeric"))

df$dist <- diag(geosphere::distm(p1,p2))
```

such that

```
> df
  id              pos1              pos2     dist
1  1 -103.3671_43.0835 -103.3660_43.0812 270.7631
2  2 -103.3634_43.0855 -103.3656_43.0872 260.3055
3  3 -103.3684_43.0884 -103.3695_43.0890 111.6475
4  4 -103.3613_43.0835 -103.3600_43.0825 153.4549
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = 1:4, pos1 = c("-103.3671_43.0835", "-103.3634_43.0855", 
"-103.3684_43.0884", "-103.3613_43.0835"), pos2 = c("-103.3660_43.0812",
"-103.3656_43.0872", "-103.3695_43.0890", "-103.3600_43.0825"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```